# How can I change tag names to fix spelling mistakes and/or improve readability?

Tags: support, tags, edits, spelling

There are tags which are wrongly spelt or unreadable. Users have created posts on the Meta sites to request fixing this issue. Unfortunately these issues have not been fixed and the moderators of those site don't know how to fix it, because **we can't create a tag with the proper spelling, since it would be marked as "too similar" to the existing tags and we'll be blocked from creating the tags with the correct spelling.**

On the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange Meta site, *Moderator* [Voltage Spike](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/96810/voltage-spike) says:

> The problem is we would have to retag all questions individually to make the change – Voltage Spike♦

Source: [This comment on a question on Electrical Engineering Meta site which got automatically deleted due to inactivity](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/remap-system-verilog-to-systemverilog-to-fix-spelling#comment18621_7376)

Current problems:

1. [I want to create a systemverilog tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280439/12311164) (This problem is also present on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange). The problem is a spelling mistake.
2. [Should [flipflop] tag be changed to [flip-flop]?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6266/238188) The problem is lack of readability.

From the upvotes that these questions have got, one might conclude that many users (myself included) would like to fix these tag spellings for **correctness and readability**.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, moderators are exempt from the restriction that newly-created tags can't be "too similar" to existing tags.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog a moderator told me that such a thing is not possible. See the edit in my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@Sonic notes in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362616/how-to-change-tag-names-to-fix-spelling-mistakes-and-or-improve-readability/362620#comment1210230_362616), ♦ moderators can create tags which are very similar to ones already existing, e.g. [flip-flop] when [flipflop] already exists. They need to do that on *one* question, copy over the tag wiki and excerpt (otherwise they're lost, or at least not easily found) and then merge the old tag into the new one. That's the proper way to rename a tag while bumping only a single question to the homepage.

Comment: @ShashankVM tagging them here has no effect. If they have not interacted with a post theu wont get pinged. Better copy the link to here and ping them elsewhere.